# Pros and cons of "orphaned" pages?

Tags: navigation, seo

I work for a publisher in the theater space in the UK. We publish news, reviews, video, and other assorted articles.

We also feature a directory of theater listings in the UK. In it, members can click on a specific city and view all listings in that city. It can be further filtered by genre and other items.

We're looking to build a seasonal guide of the best listings in a particular genre. The listings won't be limited to a specific city and the guide will also feature several articles covering the genre.

My question - should this page live anywhere or be accessible via any kind of permanent navigation? What are the pros and cons of doing this/not doing this?

Our intention is to promote this through temporary ads in a variety of guide pages in select cities.

My coworker argues that this is "good enough" and any kind of navigational affordance is unnecessary and clutters the page.

My argument is that if the page "lives somewhere" it'd be better for navigation and to give users a sense of what's where on the site.

My thought is that this guide is simply an article (it reminds me of those Time Out-esque "Top places to eat over Christmas" articles), and displaying the article category it lives in (e.g. "Seasonal Guides") along with a title, subtitle, author, location, publish date, it'd give readers a sense of place and it's helpful for SEO.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you have one large collection of events that you allow users to query based on city, genre, etc., as well as want to provide a page for featured events that can be advertised.

**Why not advertise your entire collection, with the default filter being the "Featured" list you're trying to promote?** This way, people can continue browsing by other criteria if they're interested, and they're entirely connected with the rest of your site so they can learn more about who you are and what you have to offer.

Additionally, structuring it this way allows you to be able to promote events based on whatever queries you want later (e.g. "Browse all events in your area!" or "You could use a laugh! Find a comedy to watch this weekend in your city!").

I would imagine that an orphaned page would decrease conversion and increase user abandonment. It'd also be frustrating if I as a user clicked on one of your ads, found the featured list, and was unable to find it again by navigating your site later.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWSwLw.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>